# Gauged Linear Sigma Model (GLSM) with target space $E^8$ gauge group

Tags: string-theory, gauge-theory, instantons, sigma-models

I just read a few reviews (and also Witten's original paper http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9301042) about the GLSM (Gauged Linear Sigma Model) in (2,2) and (0,2) formulations.

I have several natural simple questions,

1. In (0,2) locus (in geometric phase) it seems we only get $SU(N)$ gauge group in the target space because the vector bundle is always given by a monad like
   $$0\rightarrow V \rightarrow \mathcal{H}\rightarrow \mathcal{N}\rightarrow 0.$$
   So the question is is it possible to study all ADE gauge groups in GLSM formalism? For example is it possible to have an $E^8$ vector bundle described by a special GLSM?
2. The other question is about small instantons. The only way that I can imagine to describe small instantons on a smooth Calabi-Yau in GLSM formalism, is that the above monad describes a torsion sheaf, which means $V$ must be rank 0 everywhere except over the position of the instantons. Are there any other ways?
3. What are the limitations of GLSM formalism in general? I appreciate if someone can mention them briefly.

Comment: Consider to link to the few reviews.